# FFmpeg .jpg images to .mp4 incompatible with Windows Media Player

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg

I have a series of 10 images with which I am trying to form an animation. I have used the following code below in the command line:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i plot-%03d.jpg -r 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4
```

This creates a .mp4 file with a seemingly valid file size, however, when trying to open with Windows Media Player gives the following error:

**Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.**

I have tried many solutions from previous threads but have found no solution. I have checked that my version of windows media player is compatible with mp4, avi, wmv etc. and have tried all of these outputs also. Any ideas of the issue?

The full code:

```
M:Example\Frames_plot-001_jpg>ffmpeg -f image2 -i plot-%03
ix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4
FFmpeg version SVN-r11200, Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Fabrice Bellard,
  configuration: --enable-memalign-hack
  libavutil version: 49.5.0
  libavcodec version: 51.48.0
  libavformat version: 52.1.0
  built on Dec 11 2007 14:33:27, gcc: 3.4.5 (mingw special)
Input #0, image2, from 'plot-%03d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.4, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 4167x4167 [PAR 120:120 DAR
tb(r)
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 4167x4167 [PAR 1:1 DAR 1:1]
 kb/s,  5.00 tb(c)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
Compiler did not align stack variables. Libavcodec has been miscomp
and may be very slow or crash. This is not a bug in libavcodec,
but in the compiler. You may try recompiling using gcc >= 4.2.
Do not report crashes to FFmpeg developers.
frame=    3 fps=  3 q=4.0 Lsize=     917kB time=0.6 bitrate=12522.6
video:916kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.072455%
```

Comment: *FFmpeg version SVN-r11200* --> that's almost prehistoric. Get a binary from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ and use `ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 5 -i plot-%03d.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4`

Comment: Unfortunately I have software restrictions and can't download a newer version.

Comment: Not much to try then: How about `ffmpeg -f image2 -r 5 -i plot-%03d.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4`

Comment: No luck with that code, I assume it is just a compatability issue. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Do you need the original resolution?

Comment: Not necesarily, does that matter?

Comment: For some decoders yes, try `ffmpeg -f image2 -r 5 -i plot-%03d.jpg -vf scale=1000x1000 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4`

Comment: It does not recognise the option '-vf'

Comment: I see your build has neither filter support nor scaler. No more testable suggestions from me.

Answer (score 0):

The player doesnt support the codec. Try one it does support.  Like libx264.

Comment: Would you mind ammending my code to incorporate the above?

Comment: No point. Your build doesn't have libx264 either. In any case, H264 is a newer codec than mpeg4 so I doubt this would have worked either.